# Summing and separating blocks in a data file

Tags: python, arrays

I have various large files whose structure can be exemplified as "tmp.txt".

```
1  3.1
2  2.4 
3  7.3 
4  7.2 

1  3.2
2  2.0 
3  3.1 
4  5.2

1  3.1 
2  2.2 
3  5.2
4  2.3
```

I want to read this data file and perform two tasks: i) For unique values of the first column, calculate the sum of the y column and save the data in a single array. ii) Read the file in such a way so that I can create a list of arrays whose elements are the blocks of data, separated by a blank line, in the file.

Using the following code, I can almost satisfy my request.

```
import numpy as np

def get_sumy(data):
    result = {}
    for e in data[0,:]:
        result[e] = [i for i, j in enumerate(data[0,:]) if j == e]

    l=len(np.unique(data[0,:]))
    data_out=np.zeros((2,l),dtype=float)

    id=0
    for val in np.unique(data[0,:]):
        tmp=0
        for idx in result[val]:
            tmp= tmp+data[1,idx]
        data_out[0,id]=data[0,id]
        data_out[1,id]=tmp
        id=id+1

    return data_out

def read_file(filename):
    array_list = []

    with open(filename) as f_data:    
        for k, g in groupby(f_data, lambda x: x.startswith('\n')):
            if not k:
                array_list.append(np.array([[float(x) for x in d.split()] for d in g if len(d.strip())]))
    return array_list

filename0 ="./tmp.txt" 

data= np.loadtxt(filename0).T
data_out=get_sumy(data)
data_list=read_file(filename0)

print(data_out)
print(data_list)
```

The outputs read

```
#data_out
[[ 1.   2.   3.   4. ]
 [ 9.4  6.6 15.6 14.7]]
#data_list
[array([[1. , 3.1],
       [2. , 2.4],
       [3. , 7.3],
       [4. , 7.2]]),
 array([[1. , 3.2],
       [2. , 2. ],
       [3. , 3.1],
       [4. , 5.2]]),
 array([[1. , 3.1],
       [2. , 2.2],
       [3. , 5.2],
       [4. , 2.3]])]
```

My question is now how to optimize these functions. In particular, for some reasons that I don't understand, my `read_file` sometimes cannot correctly identify a blank line, and it fails to separate arrays. Any suggestion?